# Knockout databinding custom component

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding

I have a custom component in knockout which is used the following way (I inherited this code)

```
 <div data-bind="template: {
                name: 'error-message', data: {
                    isModified: isUserNameValid,                        
                    isValid: function () { return !isUserNameValid(); }
                }, as: 'field'
            }">
```

I am a bit confused what the following code does

```
 isValid: function () { return !isUserNameValid(); }
```

And how is this different from simply just specifying

```
 isValid: !isUserNameValid()
```

Answer (score 1):

These consrtuctions are absolutely identical and valid for Knockout. So you can use the shorter one.

Note that it is better avoid to write complex functions in the markup. Such a functions should be moved to a view model object.

```js
var model = { isUserNameValid: ko.observable() };
ko.applyBindings(model);

setTimeout(function() { model.isUserNameValid(true); }, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/html" id="error-message">
<div>Template content</div>
<div data-bind="text: isValid()"></div>
</script>

<div data-bind="template: {
                name: 'error-message', data: {
                    isModified: isUserNameValid,                        
                    isValid: function () { return !isUserNameValid(); }
                }, as: 'field'
            }">
```

Comment: Does this make any difference when the values are updated? I thought the function call updates the value only once?

Comment: @tmpdev There is no difference in the updating process, because knockout collects dependencies every time it evaluates expressions (except pureComputed) and it doesn't matter whether observable is wrapped in a function or passed directly.

Comment: @tmpdev I've added a code snipped illustrating update.